# Trouble showing webview

Tags: java, android

I need to show a web page for a several amount of seconds, then start another activity.
What I am doing is on the onResume() method, I call the Thread.sleep() and then start the new activity, but when I execute it, it doesn't show me webpage. It shows a black screen, and executes the next activity. What could i possibly be doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
public class ShowPortalActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            String url = "http://someurl.com";
            WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            // next line explained below
            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.loadUrl(url);





}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    try {
        newActivity();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

void newActivity() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    Intent intent = new Intent(ShowPortalActivity.this, Inicio.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            String url = "http://someurl.com";
            WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            // next line explained below
            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.loadUrl(url);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                                  try {
                                        newActivity();
                                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                        }
            }).start();    

}

void newActivity() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    Intent intent = new Intent(ShowPortalActivity.this, Inicio.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();   
}
```

Remove on Resume code and replace this code on create method and try now....newActivity function same as your old code....

Answer (score 0):

In your android manifest file internet permission is provided or not.

If not add the following code .

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Comment: You can try with this code from the following link that web page is viewed or not:http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/

Comment: I´ve already verified if the site is working, and its working perfectly, the problem was with the thread.sleep not allowing me to show the site before the new activity starts